# How can I Assemble 10 Products from Statechart in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have a population (pallets) of 1000. Based on rate 10 different transition is created, lets call them product.

Now after retrieval I would like to assemble the following Products into 1 unit using DES. Product 1: 10 Units, Product 2: 5 Units , .... Product10: 2 Units

Is this possible to do?

[image: StateChart]

Answer (score 0):

I made a blog post about this topic you can read here: [https://noorjax.com/2019/07/02/dynamic-batches/][1]

The idea is to combine a wait block with a batch block.

All your agents should be in a wait block and you have to check every time if there are enough products of a particular type...

so on the enter action of the wait block you do do something like this (you need to fix it and expand it for each product type and batch size:
if(agent.inState(agent.P1)){
int num=count(wait,w->w.inState(w.P1));
if(num==10){
List  pallets=findAll(wait,w->w.inState(w.P1));
for(Pallet p : pallets){
wait.free(p);
}
}
}else if(agent.inState(agent.P2)){
int num=count(wait,w->w.inState(w.P2));
if(num==5){
List  pallets=findAll(wait,w->w.inState(w.P2));
for(Pallet p : pallets){
wait.free(p);
}
}
}
[1]: https://noorjax.com/2019/07/02/dynamic-batches

Comment: I want something similar to this. Suppose, I have 200 units of each product P1, P2, P3, .... P10 in storage. Now I want to pick only 10 units of each type of product from storage. The process should initiate for only 10 units.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hello Mr. Felipe,

Can you show me how to expand this code for 2 products? Right now you have shown it with 1 Product P1. Now if I need to add another product P2.

Comment: i just changed the code for that

Comment: Mr. Felipe,

I did exactly as you told. But made one change, I place the wait block before RackStore. It seem the Wait Block doesnt release anything. Everything is sitting at the wait block. I tried adding all possible combination.

Comment: if you add the wait block before a rackstore then you are not batching and you are trying to do a completely different thing... so i can't help you without significantly more explanations